# How to read multiple files and create a single data frame from them in R?

Tags: r, rhdf5

## Objective

I have 100 hdf5 files in a folder. For a reproducible example let's consider only 2 files, namely:

```
> list.files(pattern="*.hdf5")
[1] "Cars_20160601_01.hdf5" "Cars_20160601_02.hdf5"
```

Each hdf5 file contains 2 groups, `data` and `frame`. I want to extract out 2 objects from `data` group. These are called `VDS_Veh_Speed` and `VDS_Chassis_CG_Position`. Similarly, in the `frame` group there are 3 objects. Only the object `frame` is relevant in this group.
I want to read these files and extract the relevant variables described above.

## What I tried:

```
# Create a list all the hdf5 files
temp = list.files(pattern="*.hdf5")

# Read all files and create data frames from each using the file name as df name
for (i in unique(temp)){
  data <- h5read(file = i, name = "data") # ED data
  frame <- h5read(file = i, name = "frame") # Frame numbers
  ED <- data.frame(frames = frame$frame, 
                   speed.kph.ED = round(data$VDS_Veh_Speed*1.46667*0.3048*3.6,2),
                   pedal_pos = data$CFS_Accelerator_Pedal_Position)#fps

  df <- h5read(file = i, name = "data/VDS_Chassis_CG_Position")
  df <- as.data.frame(df)
  colnames(df) <- c("y", "x", "z")
  df$speed <- ED$speed.kph.ED 
  df$pedal_pos <- ED$pedal_pos
  df$file.ID <- i
  assign(i, df)
}
```

Now, because I have all the files in the Global environment, I removed the extra objects and only kept the new dfs:

```
# Remove extra objects
rm(data, df, ED, frame, i, temp)
```

Finally, I made a list of the dfs in the environment and then created a single data frame:

```
DF_obj <- lapply(ls(), get)
fdc <- do.call("rbind", DF_obj)
```

This works for me.  But, as mentioned in the comments, `assign` should be avoided. Also, I have to manually use `rm()`, without which this code won't work. Is there any way to avoid `assign` in this context?

If you need the data files, here is the link to the 2 mentioned above:  https://1drv.ms/f/s!AsMFpkDhWcnw6g7StJp9dzZ-nCr4

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(236)`

Comment: @alistaire what does that mean?

Comment: It's a quote in the [fortunes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fortunes/index.html) package that suggests `assign` is best avoided.

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you please suggest some alternative?

Comment: Use `lapply` instead of `for` so you end up with a list instead of a mess in your global environment.

Comment: Perhaps  not a dupe, but this is well-covered in [How do I make a list of data frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061)

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for the link. In my case, the files are hdf5 format. The problem is that I don't want to directly put, say, the `data` group from each file in a list. For each file I need to first extract the relevant variables from different groups and then combine them into a data frame.

Comment: That's not any different, you just have one additional step - extracting the relevant variables.

Comment: @umairdurrani, those data files you've linked to are actually *.daq files rather than *.hd5? I just wanted to actually try what alistaire suggested on your data (instead of merely reading fortune(236)).

Comment: @Angelo, Sorry, I have uploaded the hdf5 files in the same folder now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is basically the same as your code, but with a couple minor changes. We just use a list and do normal assign to elements of the list rather than using `assign()` to create data frames in your global environment. This saves potential bugs, name clashes, and having to worry about extensive clean-up.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.hdf5")
df_list = list()  # initialize a list

# Read all files into a list of data frames
for (i in unique(temp)){
  data <- h5read(file = i, name = "data") # ED data
  frame <- h5read(file = i, name = "frame") # Frame numbers
  ED <- data.frame(frames = frame$frame, 
                   speed.kph.ED = round(data$VDS_Veh_Speed*1.46667*0.3048*3.6,2),
                   pedal_pos = data$CFS_Accelerator_Pedal_Position)#fps

  df <- h5read(file = i, name = "data/VDS_Chassis_CG_Position")
  df <- as.data.frame(df)
  colnames(df) <- c("y", "x", "z")
  df$speed <- ED$speed.kph.ED 
  df$pedal_pos <- ED$pedal_pos

  # assign to the list. We can take care of the id cols automatically
  df_list[[i]] <- df
} 

names(df) <- unique(temp)
fdc <- data.table::rbindlist(df_list, idcol = "file.ID")
```

Using `data.table::rbindlist` will be faster than using `do.call(rbind)`, and it takes care of the ID column for us based on the names of the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this doesn't work because the `i` in the loop is the name of a file because of using `unique(temp)`. So, `df_list[[i]] <- df` throws error. This is the reason that I tried to use `assign`.

Comment: Why doesn't that work? What error? `my_list = list(); my_list[["item_one"]] = mtcars; my_list[["your_filename.hdf5"]] = iris; i = "another_filename.hdf5"; my_list[[i]] <- data.frame(x = 1:2)` works just fine.

Comment: @umairdurrani Did you skip the `df_list = list()` line initializing the list before the loop??

Comment: No, I copied your code and tried it. When you do `for (i in unique(temp))`, the first `i = Cars_20160601_01.hdf5`. So, when `df_list[[i]] <- df` is run, you get an error.

Comment: `list.files`returns a vector of class `character`, so the first `i` should be `"Cars_20160601_01.hdf5"` (notice the quotes). The code from my first comment easily demonstrates that character indices work for creating new list elements. I don't know what the issue is because you won't say what the error is, but your assumption that the problem is using an element from a character vector to index a list is wrong.

Comment: I understand your point now. I probably had something messed up in my RStudio session before. After restart, your code worked flawlessly. It is faster too. Thank you very much! I didn't know that lists also have names in R.